# Vertical Radio Buttons

Tags: xpages

So what is the best method to get vertical radio buttons to display in situations with limited screen space.  I started with the standard xp:radioGroup, but I can't control the format to be vertical.

I have tried the multicolumnradiobutton on OpenNTF, but I was having problems getting an eventHandler to fire to force a partial refresh (tried using onclick).  Would love to see a sample of that since that would solve the issue of formatting.

What I am seeing at this point is if you use a radiobutton group you are stuck with a horizontal layout of buttons.  I haven't looked Dojo Radio Button to see if it was the answer.

Basically best option for vertical list of radio buttons that will allow partialRefresh of document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get **vertical** radio buttons with xp:radioGroup when you set `layout="pageDirection"`:

[image]

```
<xp:radioGroup
    id="radioGroup1"
    value="..."
    layout="pageDirection">
    ...
</xp:radioGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks don't know how I missed the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a radio button (not a group) and tie them together with the name. Then you can format them any way you want. This is useful when using Bootstrap since the radio button group puts everything in a table.